# Prove an inequality

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Prove that $\frac{n!}{n^n} < \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n \in N$. Conclude that $\frac{n!}{n^n}$ is a null sequence.

I know if we prove the inequality, I can conclude it's null, since we know $\frac{1}{n}$ is null. 
However, I don't know how to prove the inequality - squeeze theorem can't be used here since the $n! >1$ for the numerator. What can/should I use?

Comment: $n!=n(n-1)\cdots 2\cdot 1\le n\cdot n\cdots n\cdot 1= n^{n-1}$.

Comment: Try to prove this inequality: n! <n^{n-1}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have 
$$
\frac{n!}{n^n}=\frac1n\,\overbrace{\frac2n\,\frac3n\,\cdots\,\frac nn}.
$$
All the terms below the bracket are $\leq1$, and so their product is also $\leq1$. Thus
$$
\frac{n!}{n^n}\leq\frac1n\times1=\frac1n.
$$